# Is it possible when using pysnmp to allow any community string on return

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am using Python 3.6.8 with pysnmp 4.4.12 and the device I am polling works fine with easysnmp or snmpwalk/snmpget from the command line. I found out the problem. While I am sending community string xxxxxx, the return packets show the community string as public. I changed it temporarily to public to see if that would work and it did. My question is there some way to tell pysnmp to ignore the community on incoming packets?

Answer (score 0):

The original developer Ilya made it clear in many places that PySNMP aims to be standard compliant, so any violation can trigger such issues.

I took a glance on the related files and didn't see any option to skip community name check.